# Solve stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have to solve:

$dX_t=(4t-3X_t)dt+2tX_tdW_t=4tdt-X_t(3dt+2tdW_t)$

---

Let $$Y_t:=X_t \exp\Big(-3t-\int_0^t2sdW_s+\frac{2 t^3}{3}\Big)$$

$dY_t=X_td\Big[\exp \Big(-3t-\int_0^t2sdW_s+\frac{2 t^3}{3}\Big)\Big]+\exp\Big(-3t-\int_0^t2sdW_s+\frac{2 t^3}{3}\Big)dX_t+d\Big[\exp \Big(-3t-\int_0^t2sdW_s+\frac{2 t^3}{3}\Big)\Big]dX_t=$

Is this the only correct approach? Calculations will be very extensive. Maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: An alternative approach is the following: First solve the ODE $$dx_t = (4t-3x_t) \, dt$$ and then make a variation-of-constants-approach (for the SDE). However, I'm note sure whether this works out for this particular SDE (and it will also involve a lot of calculations).

Comment: i have some trouble calculating $d\Big[\exp \Big(-3t-\int_0^t2sdW_s+\frac{2 t^3}{3}\Big)\Big]$, how can I do that?

Comment: What about applying Itô's formula? However, I still don't see why you think that the definition of $Y_t$ is a good choice.

Comment: Stochastic exponential. After I apply Ito formula to $Y_t$, terms with $X_t$ should cancel each other.